# When I tried to run tensorflow, I noticed that the GPU was not being used, though I was using tensorflow GPU version. Any work around for this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

My installation had no issues, but the warning that

"This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware. You may continue installation. but you may not be able to run CUDA applications with this driver. This may occur with graphics hardware that is newer than this toolkit. In that case, it is suggested that you keep your existing driver and install the remaining portions of the CUDA Toolkit",

Was not solved.

Comment: Install latest drivers and CUDA https://medium.com/@acrosson/installing-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-keras-69bbf33dce8a

Comment: I want to use tensorflow 1.12 which is compatible with CUDA 9. so I can not install upper versions. I've tried this solution and tensorflow 1.12 did not work with CUDA 9.2 or CUDA 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you use Anaconda distribution. Once Anaconda is installed you can create a new environment where Tensorflow with GPU support will be installed by typing:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_gpuenv tensorflow-gpu # this installs it
conda activate tensorflow_gpuenv # this switches you to the tensorflow environment
```

More info [here](https://www.anaconda.com/tensorflow-in-anaconda/)

Comment: tanks for your response but I've used Anaconda Package as you said. I've noticed that every tensorflow model that I test, use only 5% from GPU. Is there any way to force tensorflow use more GPU?

Comment: First rate the post as a acceptable answer. Second, what do you mean that it uses 5% GPU ? Is it 5% of the GPU RAM, 5% of the GPU CUDA Cores ? On what operating system do you monitor it ? If you are monitoring on Windows check the Copute and Copy charts ... not 3D, Video Encode, Video Decode and etc.

Comment: yes,understood. The CUDA cores usage is about 38% and the GPU RAM is about full. Is there any way to use more cores?